# What is the meaning of g0ofg1?

Tags: ats

I often see code like the following line in ATS:

```
val xs = g0ofg1(xs)
```

The function g0ofg1 looks like some kind of casting. What does it actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an overloaded symbol.

There are many types in ATS for which there exist an indexed and a non-indexed variant.

- For instance, there exists `int(i)` (for some `i` of sort `int`) and `int`. Both types are for integers, but the former is indexed by `int` sort.
- Another example: `string` (just a string) and `string(n)` (length-indexed string)

`g0ofg1` is for converting an indexed type into a non-indexed one. It's a castfn, so this operation has no runtime cost associated with it.

`g1ofg0` is for going in the other direction: from non-indexed to indexed type.